# android windowSoftInputMode doesnt resize layout

Tags: android, keyboard

I have an ActivityGroup.  Сhild Activity has a set of EditText(s). When a virtual keyboard appears, the layout does not moves up and user can't see an input field.
Setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in `manifest.xml` doesn't give required  result.

```
    <activity android:name="com.boyko.organizer.activities.editors.AddCarActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="MainActivityGroupWithFrame"   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**EDITED**

Found strange behavior. i have custom horizontalscrollview  as a parent and two childs: activityGroup and listview. When remove scrollview and set activitygroup as parent, than all works fine.

Comment: try this android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize" & use this link http://www.vogella.com/blog/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/

Comment: doestn help. i've just try different combinations

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest you is put your layout in **ScrollView** and then in the manifest add
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`.
Somthing like this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

          <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:id="@+id/tv_message" 
            style="@style/Text.Large.Bold.Colored.Red" />

            // other widget
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I have some custom horizontalScrollView in which i inflated two child activities: activitygroup and listView.

Comment: Ohh dear. I have not worked much on that. Let me check if I get something.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that did it for me was doing it in code, by putting

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

into my activity's `onCreate` method.

All XML attempts did not work at all, although I have heard of some hacks that seem to work at some devices by setting more than one state value in `android:windowSoftInputMode` which is obviously a bit of a hack since Google states [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) this might lead to "*undefined results*".

Anyways the line above worked fine on every device I have tried so far.